# adding the category to the admin column for a custom post type?

Tags: wp-admin

I have built a custom post type called article and the information given on the admin summary screen is sparse. I was able to add the featured image post thumbnail image using the http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column from a tutorial.

However I would like to be able to get an overview of the categories and sub categories that these posts have had assigned to them on the admin page. ie adding a column for that part?

Here is the code that I have used to register the taxonomy in the custom post types code

Comment: You could use a plugin like [Codepress Admin Columns](https://wordpress.org/plugins/codepress-admin-columns/)

Answer (score 24):

The [register_taxonomy](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_taxonomy/) function has a parameter called `show_admin_column` that will handle adding a column.  Have you tried that?

eg:

```php
register_taxonomy(
    'my_tax, 
    'post_type', 
    array(
        'label'             => 'My Taxonomy',
        'show_admin_column' => true,
        )
);
```

Comment: Please,  add code and explain how using it answers the quesiton. If you just want to ask something to the OP, use the comments.

Comment: It's 2020 and the answer is still working. Thanks for the help. Upvote from my side.

Answer (score 8):

After some searching, I have found a solution using the `manage_edit-${post_type}_columns` filter and the `manage_${post_type}_posts_custom_column` action.

The columns are created with the filter and then the column is populated with the action. I assume additional columns could be added and populated quite easily using the ideas in this link http://justintadlock.com/archives/2011/06/27/custom-columns-for-custom-post-types

```
add_filter('manage_edit-article_columns', 'my_columns');
function my_columns($columns) {
    $columns['article_category'] = 'Category';
return $columns;
}

add_action( 'manage_article_posts_custom_column', 'my_manage_article_columns', 10, 2 );

function my_manage_article_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
global $post;

switch( $column ) {

    /* If displaying the 'article_category' column. */
    case 'article_category' :

        /* Get the genres for the post. */
        $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, 'article_category' );

        /* If terms were found. */
        if ( !empty( $terms ) ) {

            $out = array();

            /* Loop through each term, linking to the 'edit posts' page for the specific term. */
            foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
                $out[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                    esc_url( add_query_arg( array( 'post_type' => $post->post_type, 'article_category' => $term->slug ), 'edit.php' ) ),
                    esc_html( sanitize_term_field( 'name', $term->name, $term->term_id, 'article_category', 'display' ) )
                );
            }

            /* Join the terms, separating them with a comma. */
            echo join( ', ', $out );
        }

        /* If no terms were found, output a default message. */
        else {
            _e( 'No Articles' );
        }

        break;

    /* Just break out of the switch statement for everything else. */
    default :
        break;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Nearly the same question:
i want a extra column "categorie" in the admin screen.
"categorie" is a taxonomy made with Divi Machine. The slug is art_category
In my child theme functions.php i managed to make ACF fields visible, even sortable but those are ACF fields.
The column Categorie is visible. However there are no values.

It must be in here somewhere:

```
    if ( 'artcategory' === $column ) {
    $artcategory = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'art_category', true );

    if ( ! $artcategory ) {
      _e( 'n/b' );
    } else {
      echo $artcategory;
    }
  }


What am i doing wrong.....
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/253041)